# AngularJS conflicts with JavaScript minifier

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code, which works fine:

```
angular.module('foo', []).config(
  function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
);
```

However, after minification it looks like this:

```
angular.module('foo', []).config(function(n) { n.html5Mode(true); });
```

And AngularJS crashes with some internal exception. I think I understand why it crashes, but what is a workaround?

Comment: you need see [A Note on Minification](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very known and popular issue, you can inject your dependancies in this way

```
.directive('someDirective', ['$window', function ($window) { .....
```

You can learn more about it under this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)

Another solution is to use [ng-anotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)

If you use Angular 1.3 you can turn on [strictdi](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi)

replace this part

```
.config(
  function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
);
```

to this

```
.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
]);
```

Comment: Highly recommend ng-annotate.  It's very fast - worlds faster than ngmin.

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan I didn't understand how exactly I should change **my** code above?